# Incorrect comparison of three input characters

Tags: c, if-statement, dev-c++

I have the following program, which compares three characters and outputs their comparison.

When I run the program, whenever I input three integers only the last else (all initials are different) statement runs correctly for its condition. But, for other conditions, only the last else if (first and last initials are the same) runs. I also checked it after adding curly braces but nothing changed.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
    char ch1, ch2, ch3;

    printf("Enter 3 character values into ch1, ch2, and ch3: ");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &ch1, &ch2, &ch3);

    if(ch1==ch2)
    {
      if(ch2==ch3)
      printf("All initials are the same!\n");

      else
      printf("First two initials are the same!\n");
     }
 
    else if(ch2==ch3)
    {
    printf("Last two initials are the same!\n");
    }
  
    else if(ch1==ch3)
    {
    printf("First and last initials are the same!\n");
    }
  
  
    else
    {
    printf("All initials are different!\n");
    }
 
   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The program is comparing 3 *characters*, not 3 *integers*.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is just a writing mistake.

Comment: OK, so what is your input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Why not indent your code sensibly? Also -- why not use braces? Even when they are not strictly required, they can make code easier to read.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea which else goes with which if (or even which you think goes with which) - This is almost certainly a case where formatting your code will help find the issue !

Comment: This program and understanding of it would greatly benefit from proper indentation.

Comment: Your code works fine for me ... so long as I don't put any spaces between the entered letters. If you do that, then the spaces will be read as the input characters.

Comment: It actually has a proper indentation, I couldn't display it while pasting it, sorry.

Comment: What is your input? Spaces and Enters included ... like "my input is F<Space>O<Tab>O<Enter>" or "F,<Space>O,<Space>O<Enter>"

Comment: Yes, you are right. I put spaces and that's why I wasn't working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted works just fine, *so long as you don't enter any whitespace characters between the input initials!* (I tested it with `AAA`, `AAB`, `ABA`, `ABB` and `ABC`, and all gave the correct response.)

However, if you were to enter spaces between the initials (i.e. enter `A A B`), then the space characters will be read as input (that's how the `%c` format specifier works) so, in that case, the three initials will *actually* be `A`,   and `A` – giving a seemingly incorrect answer.

To skip (optional) whitespace characters between the inputs, simply add a space between each of the `%c` format specifiers, like this:

```c
scanf("%c %c %c", &ch1, &ch2, &ch3);
```